# Python Decode Base64 qUncompress Image

Tags: python, qt

I'm running into a bit of a problem and could use some help.
I have here a small pyqt app that displays a pixmap.

```
import sys
import qtcompress
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

def window():
   str_image = 'AAASDHicnVdlUBSO076DOySlUzqkuxuU7pRG8hAE6QY5uhvkaCXlSEGk4TyPUvBoCQlJT+CkO/7+Pr/f3mfm2Zjd2f2wszuzyUYGmiSEDIQAAIBEW0vN5J9W+Y/4eP8k3N135Z8C+T/RNsP/hwh8l6R/PoGPlpU/AEBE+R+BgKISun85D9zNLAMs9fXknL29hBxdvJ1chUK8fABAgLmZhqAM4P9GXkTvF4+/qtegGj4PJUQtfzRxvGj5zKoX8LL2HPJLSsdk2UW2jN6TyoFnbX60PnBS8w9/AN5NNEmGwGmQKZOLzaHszv296JfCQ08KW28/PXvL6rEF9u9Df1aj7qr5RJnqVxPEnd8YzovdXdm3JJ4/Zxm9Jjp8H8ZkD34UlbvNW9/Sqp3bcCLtTG2q5NZ/YZOQDZ/hmv1meStA+XV6z6DwIIb36fJkkrtNyi5me6JNI7ac6psIkwtxFsa9Zj/1B8LoUwGDfTL67dvsKOVb11TK1aE/rXA/lnenYY3NXqW0RGznCi6WI60Sxu/yva3ipa2fvfbQC1IyfZbD/r0e5pZyk7ETYZ5ufqrjbrfkW33JnJcfpqhRekDl5ZOht6zipta2MNwqsW/+Znb85emH1oiIb/TdblzPqeOWe1sbrmbc1EdXuJ9Taysq57G+aTHT0vnlerbypH+TWrjgZqzzHNNW2bzO8+fH1zEr+iWUm4vY9AgyVogsd8+QMIHfXsGvLE6/YHn/lWGhnosFyem7oy8dMpURdnd0b02Ny1mKU4J5PjZBiCWmQyWIF7KfGorbropYP9bfSh7WC1AepO5Hbb0/m0mclgnrGdkyCt0TLb7ssLL6lday5M6DE8Zouhpgt945Nue5rrHIw0A2zhHwduENZSGHswoHBzw9c4tpl5ebf0GH/YdA5NfkllXpJO+2kbJMAZs2AYufvaO2JKT68PSGrmTFR8Uum3sqgm0Pf3ew08hTGlhL+gmYITT8Y4vefJYYpuu2Rm1abp9pPQqROBKpPp5E/GQL85R73+zLa70hqPAHHYYOcYhi1AxO5mw6z2Kk5crV9W/AztUskmvp96Ei9TaxlDnd6S+gGRU7rr7nvvZSYKbL0KGw0dZM6ybzwJWqTeP2IfB1L5l45MLiHmUQhFHS9I5FIYVi4K7nge9C91W5QhIuVMD3k4OEmvwvIZ+FtpcVw/UvO5x66kXfojJDstf50kx7HXjQNEA5kE1+YuQLJKV9kn5OfBD0CtkHXxrdbFozLmlp6b0/avMLF/fVQ/tK6EovSTV2v8m8qcuVz4DJ23bkTAQ41Z4attrlmpf6Cz61Hckrt3GXj+SLvLO8uok+ybpSTK2fWNQxQArm3yi+gvxVZWQqZFx0//3xSmilZdOdITWyI+98jfhT0bRa88FlyUEXh+diXSDipUHmi/AIKm6Lj8rdZ5Kn5wMAHDIoAMQKAOKr/H/My+9Z9Q736LcClc6BjfaJ94B2C/KKAsJo2X/3pFhbTdUspGS/WD/N3i1wOGqnhJ++2onayTFtg95QgMvY0fibaIwdzUIVRToFbZ06HwGeOi84WZ3qHX5+K1R9nisbIeNebQaO0bV8q2NVtWw0WzeGQxNIvUf/0ukx0uUpZ1x1OBazftnbPDDUzJQO3xSCrJyv7Cidy977f7+P+LmTn7TWF/HbQNihNvMcOI8B750cKgHk+6ClSivHAOK/25vKl6MDKXWF8H3RaWXTtsz6xWWp3/C6fcnZpXHPApid2GzH+F4MvKkYQ29+XV10i1TrUBskZVa4aEK97JoNRegK93HCPSCfhseYRWavZ/dyIZ8q4DASGK9HQt27xzB6viGHFJgjHMbg1O1Yc+9e0Vy3UA/vdvXoj3K9F7Q5EcRduzjcqKjpwXv0zHzfUfyWSFw+L46JLkcFxgBJMQdIACvoYdiSundFCJPJachVCrzMrD3QvCtgpzR45WTdmwCAVry/cYCHj+0Jj++9L2SatDfSjZlBQ4jb/K0OIjIh/Fo/2stoRcdO8uD9DXBlsbbGyOuzdOm2s+J1qFv/MRP9jNJ7yLljBPmm6poUFF9lSoZXOomVHbqmkoWn3kGWXUWWHGQoAnyLp8cIVMJjBPZ3dHVddr/vP57sCy+Y2pwCRFzbrNJI9n355cjJTC1TAvLazRJVVgU9JQOhpwjVjTQ5fWI80owhfM4UoCc4c7+koiuB/JRHFYhRaWHbzk5ifF3gQbr3TeyiAwtzEho3E8i/5h6vHqu+X2YwStYJiiYHwwTMpBJv9KeUy9GU42lGhUeCfnQ3D9mUOH3WkfFE3vvLPcHd5Fav6KC15a+t9fa/sB92cHz5AAwSziAA2bZkQe6d37ArTyqmE4N2sZSI4bdlDUKsWi4LnC/e1PCnRGijlFVQ/rQrvS3t55VLHXGPcNZGucupxHtwLxSYh3GCiHDZYrRqA1OEcOkFiXI/jywWgCl5n2vGAGGEzzmr4Gu/QpvweaCsPWDFhEGWZEyP9PpDaRD0+kR1zTFrGLoczfqLLNpZDSFCddiW8YRCJUTUxyfJZ2yRQZFVYHnHBBtPJ8eMTxZb58Ctuq6pGrccooB3YxAbhfc6Shd40SMcFSrSzvFEgQ+p82GygsyW75hU1dq9C7tQzUV/mzVb2qDRzfNLknAGmM/Cqubwx/2ZuxKNwyeK6ROer83S0tL3kfJsfjYAhbuLjQp4OOoCycNYk2M5624Xi58GxMWRGkgAxXHZjCwKr3i6lv3eOePz+muvvbECTQpaYX8oHwGUafs36+3+yOsmDOESDmI5OJox8PDBYQMVrYCoTdnj5gm2ChuHZMJL63Uc7iqCZfIIOQ2H32LxCppqOAok0/Ao8ug6hWGjQuaStQHoTrTyChWg/LoYnVzYiLygp3u126wNtZzKowISPuRKC2VlO9YqQGn/cHXsZxOzJCnJwMtdykMj8o5TN58Xhsct4Sjh3ixdHu+g91ajThd/dQMuNhNQHCM+5SNJSVvm3yJsRbdF6OQShO+5KOgzPpIlcjt44HGmbx0jUPTqfwVRmh8IyXOqLdkn9VJA59oH+AeCOfqCBNBr5rVpddj7Xe9y+LauwAk5koY1BmGKZwn24KCgf+x3KNePMGMcP5q/7OXNhdF8B+ceYGDrLNHj9aPB+gBm2TCzsT3gmhG3unXEm3s/Gx6iLHasp8pUpxmLZpqYnd8FOebNLLToKIKo/cuW3rwyNitB0edsb4F2bm6u6TfeD5CDn3T0dTKsEjteTsQ1DhmYqvR8bdVaVAmZMHm6LXAmupNholS9pLuoYBEzZu6njFT2pZbufAxQumRWVVKH0oIgVdSdXOmWtOhHG7jksh259A758+w7+I9Hm6uBi2hZG1rZ5e8bJjJau0klrzWTCZG1MBdSC9/YXUtEwAvU+SNji5LWgVdZF67WL65y5TQIS4eTXNvKEweys9jME7mejjFPNQjW/rj14lSfOcSfxieO4bSfJ/V7wQuIKFKa05ajzKooBd8noMbeUEZZfYxMVQsBbrAeg0MyCBshHu4fJnSQWVjnIDQvpU9dcZ8CmdZtrMW/LR29xVbswxHYMDWDM6dX78mz/Ss3Pwz91GTiFqhGMQ+W0CI9RKYDxT7ywwo5d4Q0phveWYF9zmddesvAjFDWqul16hmhAPDrmoDsJ6bJs7mP5ZnJfc73dl1aaJ7UchJwDl+xZ6vRcmnUbduza4xIFDvF4OoCRS4vyJFN79kwnmyBoTlduoVz/EpQyoc0qVISuZT0INpCXPCFTIwVWBlJL8dOiCagG6Tzb6Fiq0lWvRgxAXQadkxvrWIuSZIWnigqP4uLVlouThydk+6MWUDrpFoedPk5y2FWynUdT46SsoeR+//1+8iPtn9mntqdEZOdbUtJJTAFwCDte56t8Th+KE97OKb1p4G6evNJ6vZBqBBB/Sf7qQBMzgOChXaqf7Plak2Mdov2oxDTeOnNFpdmib5IQ8kg1rpq2hZ+fh5REXEiHhmrhjuox31Fvfmuu2pUpR5vQgyuizkJ8EZUbwEOMF5rhpA5BiYMWqc3wBEy/6sThJooeTFUniyiyK1awK20UKZQGEIUbx9OCi5+b8xulSfPq6oTvbFfDYA9vk/HD5bqMPT6Zv0hX32OAk1PZGyOV9nEzolI/5Znh7SRIR7ji36ldjd9qItVJJ7qodX6KHppPGBFAcWUJEXg6IizC6q4jowtd8ulA4vKU8fGldKzXHiJ0qjLrN3Zq735tPCCsn+mSObL/nQuY5w01oQ7fxcEQ3vKtf1RMXOM3RYeTNLCVPqNhvNp8gOAbC0vcXLIqeqzDUvjUjf6ffyfiUp0bk+LNBupZDbHTAAoiVuPHIMOwT9kg0xfN6oIJgdoYlVs6ZxdXhAIra+NFtAlq70lgjP3qQ86EQnG4WRjQd1S4e4tLru6fR3PBcEIGf1aku+aLcrJUwSPeavN/fqx2Ze9Pxm1flxqx4Q9rGGi3y6x08K8whbMVMbPAj9Tks11JRRYvOIQnd/rZ6RAJ/qE8QKcjhoJXj/ca+bEMpm61eqGqnhYhaidDubczZWp5nWWT++COzzCcvHMyGuQRqC8ZzxcxMWFc7xMyRey83MmgAsJWbZmgiOL6Np1MT/NmhwnzHj1il1KQqRIgAZBgufDNh5jmEf2VsUp2YNk+gdUNSzV5G6lSNPX2RSVOjnNbG39f86AMsfKbutl4dhQ6h2JF16p+R1dm3FVfUdl3fNLWzuh0Vw5Mz6z3NBlHZCJNL1Pwp+wNphYENaY48GCZLyPZtI0+dGfp6SKAYNB84FAgM+5YFq5mC/PlfmDy8PIywVJ7R5Si0yKSyXRKrW0BZDdlGntX9h8z+FkIIt10cG0Qy/80psIyot0LXrNiCrHPR9vphFJ4eXW5Xk5zgzUCmN6bEe/ymFcEUdC3dp/v8pcACDHIJo0M3QbG8+6EZmj7ktTgJurdOn1ph6stfReoqlelM5iyQSN2YolegXjekxS5+09JKqZrOCZ5tASWu8iwEftdsLqBEu10tkruRg7bgB9/+2QFpVF9/o38up51FmbheS9FxAgom7rdFTw9ALkQyVXrTnpu/QVZ4yuv/Xyd1XHViFRiga/LifEu2a5YyYsfASsPR709ZLi6UXhhrC4fR8+3/AngEzwmWcDk0yLJO9wNHXclz6H7Egj2tybnC3tJlwQLCX3o2YtPLhK1ih3OpHdkT/gT7ChdubsiTXg7pHMQ08m+aC9osVVKQDADV36iPRfHS5KYQMkEz7/+uA3/xFe7MSt16lyXUXbTeQ7OrIcojy2U496n6xJv9V3SxZT7asH8y0ttNGmhgqHqE9BmcsTeMmwmmBb2VFOFpz+uK9YHt/mwdgus82ATxThARNVRtZn+Jw8pmhvqq607ZTavJMOE0jOfQeZMJmfidrKQpOeNAhxdaXR0NBgCzIARQBk8PZo3JG653UbIwsPs2oGZuyze9vV/Icosou4QnsI7LCFhA0RNb0N9PGrDBEsMmwXg80RW/U/JG+rAYD5+fmk/Nn8DlBZ8VTP+TDiWVpdYJXY08caryLomBzzZ+oSNFg+vJgIWWHhVDMI3TkTwemk/DzE2qvi82StsbYszGMJKQwGIIauhj52d7eCj+zWghGViF9Xm4zXJm1yi8+YPTa6v1M7f8MBt2KCGQYEZD0SuZHhk4oGFF8GmyNvd6U5FX6iNEZPT9Mt7az6tBazThIQtNzrqrzy6vXw9jnSU8uswT43Mm/W/CInznZkIgPuHfRAfC0csYuQX73ZXl1tOfDJtXH9IT2He3G7uLgYBbiv99HJqlRj1M53ZrCQEqJqPV780G1bv4XvcHDEIBc/0euMNWMVJh3JFPlUFrpdWLzIH/EtKLW5sTEZjjVpN5eMnOfcp/nx+kHICqPiKqg0OJ3U3T9gUc3Ly6aPT4oulqTW/JRaXN4dsgsJwiy4lfdhBlePVokYFUKMZmb0vDLhSm89zotHuc291HeDLvFiMFAaVS/YPQSRcBIOnP0RQGcv2S74aMYw4h7136vw4K0ytu/c3nj2LJW8PbMYswzvhkPC9feDxJerb4U1xub0T9OKbv2MruNJPrnC74SVLz73tE4EU0PvSYfD7zRN/+K2TBPNYzYiAUFhQPnIG5axlCmO0mvWRsA/aKsbqDU9cYj5Hz3VwP4='

   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   win = QWidget()
   l1 = QLabel()

   image = qtcompress.decode_thumbnail(str_image)
   l1.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

   vbox = QVBoxLayout()
   vbox.addWidget(l1)
   win.setLayout(vbox)
   win.setWindowTitle("QPixmap Demo")
   win.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

Here is the decode_thumbnail function

```
def decode_thumbnail(str_image):
   bytearray = QtCore.QByteArray.fromBase64(str_image)
   bytearray = QtCore.qUncompress(bytearray)
   image = QtGui.QImage()
   image.fromData(bytearray, 'PNG')
```

I've looked around a lot and can't seem to find any examples of anyone unpacking a string from base64 and then using qUncompress. Python is not my forte in any way, so I apologize if this is a simple question.

Comment: Is this real code? Asking because `the string` is obviously not a valid base 64 encoded image.

Comment: Correct, I can edit and add a string to the post. It is a valid base64 string I am using in the actual code.

Comment: I edited the post and added a valid base64 qcompressed image, its a png of a sphere with alpha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `decode_thumbnail` function.  It isn't returning anything.

Change the last line from

```
    image.fromData(bytearray, 'PNG')
```

to

```
    return image.fromData(bytearray, 'PNG')
```

Alternatively, as `QImage.fromData` is a static method, you don't need an `image` object, so you can just write

```
def decode_thumbnail(str_image):
   bytearray = QByteArray.fromBase64(str_image)
   bytearray = qUncompress(bytearray)
   return QImage.fromData(bytearray, 'PNG')
```

Comment: What is the difference between doing `return image` on the next line and `return image.fromData`?

Comment: @ChrisPerrella: `image.fromData` returns an image read from the data.  It does not read the data it is given and put it in `image`.  So if you do nothing with the result of `image.fromData` you will basically be creating an image from some data and immediately discarding that image. Besides, `QImage.fromData` is a static method (i.e. it belongs to the `QImage` class and not to instances of that class) so you can call it without creating an image.  I've now edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: Ah okay I understand now, interesting. That explains a number of issues I was running into previously. Thanks!